# scikit-learn: applying an arbitary function as part of a pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I've just discovered the [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) feature of scikit-learn, and I find it very useful for testing different combinations of preprocessing steps before training my model.

A pipeline is a chain of objects that implement the `fit` and `transform` methods. Now, if I wanted to add a new preprocessing step, I used to write a  class that inherits from `sklearn.base.estimator`. However, I'm thinking that there must be a simpler method. Do I really need to wrap every function I want to apply in an estimator class?

Example:

```
class Categorizer(sklearn.base.BaseEstimator):
    """
    Converts given columns into pandas dtype 'category'.
    """

    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self


    def transform(self, X):
        for column in self.columns:
            X[column] = X[column].astype("category")
        return X
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a general solution (working for many other use cases, not just transformers, but also simple models etc.), you can write your own **decorator** if you have state-free functions (which do not implement fit), for example by doing:

```
class TransformerWrapper(sklearn.base.BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func

    def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._func(X, *args, **kwargs)
```

and now you can do

```
@TransformerWrapper
def foo(x):
  return x*2
```

which is the equivalent of doing

```
def foo(x):
  return x*2

foo = TransformerWrapper(foo)
```

which is what sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer is doing under the hood.

Personally I find decorating simpler, since you have a nice separation of your preprocessors from the rest of the code, but it is up to you which path to follow.

In fact you should be able to decorate with sklearn function by

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

@FunctionTransformer
def foo(x):
  return x*2
```

too.

Answer (score 6):

The [`sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html) class can be used to instantiate a scikit-learn transformer (which can be used e.g. in a pipeline) from a user provided function.

Comment: Unfortunately the FunctionTransformer seems to enforce that the output is a numpy ndarray with only numeric content, which doesn't work at every stage of the pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's worth to mention that [`sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer(..., validate=True)`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html) has a `validate=False` parameter:

> **validate** : `bool`, optional `default=True`
>
> Indicate that the input `X` array should be checked before calling `func`. If validate is false, there will be no input validation. **If it
>   is true, then `X` will be converted to a 2-dimensional NumPy array or
>   sparse matrix**. If this conversion is not possible or `X` contains `NaN` or
>   infinity, an exception is raised.

So if you are going to pass non-numerical features to `FunctionTransformer` make sure that you explicitly set `validate=False`, otherwise it'll fail with the following exception:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'your non-numerical value'
```

Comment: What about the case of a string that *is* convertible to a numpy array? :\